# How to enable filters on protected excel file in OLE2 ABAP

Tags: excel, abap, vba

I am able to add filters using OLE2 in ABAP and my excel file getting created successfully. The issue is filter is not working - I can see filters attached to field columns but I can not click.

Comment: Give you code. What happens when you click? Are they disabled or what? Give screenshot

Comment: When you protect a sheet in Excel there's a tickbox "Allow Filtering" in the protection dialog. If that's not ticked you can add the filters but can't use them. I suspect that's what's happening here

Comment: @HarassedDad : exactly this is what I have to write in ABAP code, I have tried setting this property to true but it’s not working. If possible please can you share code block how to lock sheet and allow filter using ABAP code.

Comment: I would advice you to NOT use OLE, because Microsoft tends to change everything every time it changes Office versions.
Take a look at ABAP2EXCEL in github (or something like that... google for "ZCL_EXCEL")

Comment: @Suncatcher : Yes they are coming disabled. Below is code which I have :

Comment: @Suncatcher : Yes they are coming disabled. Below is code which I have :
<pre>
CALL METHOD OF w_excel 'RANGE' = w_range
    EXPORTING
    #1 = 'A1'                                       "  Column A1  TO D11   Range
    #2 = 'F1'.
  CALL METHOD OF w_range 'AutoFilter' = w_filtering.
  PERFORM err_hdl USING 'AutoFilter'.  
</pre>
<br/> I dont know how to upload Image here but what I have figured out is I have to enable "use AutoFilter" checkbox under "Review >> Protect Sheet >>" then in Popup "use AutoFilter".<br/> Please help me how can I set this checkbox using ABAP code.<br/>Thanks-

Comment: Insert your code [as appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), not as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATA: go_application TYPE ole2_object,
      go_column      TYPE ole2_object,

CALL METHOD OF go_application 'Columns' = go_column.
CALL METHOD OF go_column 'AutoFit'.
SET PROPERTY OF go_column 'AutoFilter' = 1.
 CALL METHOD OF go_sheet 'Protect'
      EXPORTING
        #1  = 'pass' " Password
        #2  = 1 " Protect Drawing Objects
        #3  = 1 " Protect Contents
        #4  = 1 " Protect Scenarios
        #5  = 0
        #6  = 0
        #7  = 0
        #8  = 0
        #9  = 0
        #10 = 0
        #11 = 0
        #12 = 0
        #13 = 0
        #14 = 0
        #15 = 1.
```

Where #15 put filter ON. Give me feedback if it worked for you